# setOnDateChangeListener for CalendarView does not work

Tags: java, android, calendarview

I am trying to have a fragment for CalendarView in my adroid app. If I change the date then the toast should get printed but it does not do that. I want the toast to be printed if the user changes the date. Can someone find the bug in my code?
Thank you!

```
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {

public CalendarFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

CalendarView cal;
Long date;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);

    cal = (CalendarView) v.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    date = cal.getDate();

    cal.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            if(cal.getDate() != date) {
                date = cal.getDate();
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Year=" + year + " Month=" + month + " Day=" + dayOfMonth, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //cal.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    });

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already inflated the view in `onCreateView()`. But you are are doing it twice.
Change  your `onCreateView()` by

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);

    cal = (CalendarView) v.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    date = cal.getDate();

    cal.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            if(cal.getDate() != date) {
                date = cal.getDate();
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Year=" + year + " Month=" + month + " Day=" + dayOfMonth, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //cal.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    });

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return v;
}
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: This is correct. I was just looking over the question and finally found the problem when you answered. GG