# setOnDateChangeListener() of CalenderView

Tags: java, android

I am working a calendar project in Android Studio. When I click on a date it opens a new Activity.The problem is that if a date is already selected ( like when you open a calendar you can see the current date already selected ), when I click on it, it gives me no response. How can I change this. This was not a problem from me when I was testing the application in the Android Virtual Device but when I installed the application in my phone this problem occurred.

Check the photo that I have given, the date that I selected does not give response but when I was testing it on a AVD , if I clicked on a selected date it gave me response.

[image]

Here is my code for the method, it works like this, It first check if there is any event saved on the date selected. If yes then it open an Alert box showing the event otherwise it open an activity where I can save the event

```
    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            date = i2 + "" + i1 + "" + i;
            Date = Integer.parseInt(date);
            Log.e(TAG,"int date="+Date+"");
            Log.e(TAG,"string date="+date+"");
            //firstly check if an entry exists for the current date.
            Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();

            while(res.moveToNext()) {
                if (res.getInt(0) == Date) {    //only runs if it find the id for this date.
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                    buffer.append("Id :" + res.getString(0) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Event Name :" + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Event Location :" + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Event Discription :" + res.getString(3) + "\n\n");

                    //when an id is present for event, than there must be an entry for attendees, So search by date(id) for attendees.
                    Cursor cursor = myDb2.getAllData();
                    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String test=cursor.getInt(0)+"";
                        if (test.contains(date)) {
                            Log.e(TAG,"it reached here");
                            buffer.append("Event Attendee :" + cursor.getString(1) + "\n\n");
                        }
                    }
                    // show message
                    showMessage("Data", buffer.toString());
                    return;
                }
            }
                //if no entry is found then pass the id as Date and shift to activity_date_selected activity ).
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, dateSelected.class);
                    intent.putExtra("date message", Date);
                    intent.putExtra("day message", i2);
                    intent.putExtra("month message", i1);
                    intent.putExtra("year message", i);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Please do not down vote my question. I am new to stackoverflow and programming. Any kind of help will be useful.

Comment: Can you show the code for calendar activity?

Comment: It's difficult to answer without seeing the code responsible. Possibly you need to switch types of events you use from "select" to "click" or something.

Comment: I have added the code, now please answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setOnDateChangeListener for CalendarView does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36168720/setondatechangelistener-for-calendarview-does-not-work)