# Method setOnDateChangeListener() of CalenderView not working properly

Tags: java, android

I am working a calendar project in Android Studio. When I click on a date it opens a new Activity.The problem is that if a date is already selected ( like when you open a calendar you can see the current date already selected ), when I click on it, it gives me no response. How can I change this. This was not a problem from me when I was testing the application in the Android Virtual Device but when I installed the application in my phone this problem occurred.

Check the photo that I have given, the date that I selected does not give response but when I was testing it on a AVD , if I clicked on a selected date it gave me response.

[Calendar View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x7QA.png)

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new 
 CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, 
 int i, int i1, int i2) {
        date = i2 + "" + i1 + "" + i;
        Date = Integer.parseInt(date);
        Log.e(TAG,"int date="+Date+"");
        Log.e(TAG,"string date="+date+"");
        //firstly check if an entry exists for the current date.
        Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();

        while(res.moveToNext()) {
            if (res.getInt(0) == Date) {    
//only runs if it find the id for this date.
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                buffer.append("Id :" + res.getString(0) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Event Name :" + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Event Location :" + res.getString(2) + 
 "\n");
                buffer.append("Event Discription :" + res.getString(3) + 
 "\n\n");

                //when an id is present for event, than there must be an 
 entry for attendees, So search by date(id) for attendees.
                Cursor cursor = myDb2.getAllData();
                while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String test=cursor.getInt(0)+"";
                    if (test.contains(date)) {
                        Log.e(TAG,"it reached here");
                        buffer.append("Event Attendee :" + 
cursor.getString(1) + "\n\n");
                    }
                }
                // show message
                showMessage("Data", buffer.toString());
                return;
            }
        }
            //if no entry is found then pass the id as Date and shift to 
activity_date_selected activity ).
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, dateSelected.class);
                intent.putExtra("date message", Date);
                intent.putExtra("day message", i2);
                intent.putExtra("month message", i1);
                intent.putExtra("year message", i);
            startActivity(intent);
      }
   });
}
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is documented behavior.

You select the current day in `CalendarView`, and click on it again. The "selected" day hasn't changed, right? So the `OnDateChangeListener`.`onSelectedDayChange` shouldn't get fired, because in fact the selected day didn't change.

You could try to workaround this by initially NOT selecting the current Day.
If this behavior comes automatically, try to set the selected day to `null`.
This way you should get the callback fired, even if someone selects the current day.

If thats not feasible, and you must somehow preselect today, you could try to fire your callback manually i.e. in `onStart` or so

Comment: It is as I said, this was not a problem, when I was testing it in Android Virtual device,I easily clicked on a selected date and got a response but when 
I installed it in my phone, is was a major issue,I think it was due to change in Operating system

Comment: @MuhammadAhsanMukhtar Sorry, But your comment doesn't make sense to me. I guess you are NOT targeting "Virtual Devices" with your app. The behavior on an emulator is different then that on actual phones (and it even changes on different manufacturers). In Android you are supposed to work around this issues. I also do not get what you mean by "change in operating System". Wasn't your virtual device an Android which is ALWAYS based on Linux (Operating System)?

Comment: I also see you asking this question twice 
@MuhammadAhsanMukhtar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180323/setondatechangelistener-of-calenderview now somebody (me) gave you an answer, yet you are to lazy to try and refuse a solution just because it worked on your "virtual device". I consider this rude behavior and the only answer you *should* get is restrict your app to virtual devices where it works. StackOverflow isn't there to do your actual work

Comment: Sorry if you found it rude, I am new to programming and don't know how to ask the right question. I asked the same question again because the last question was not answered.

Comment: @MuhammadAhsanMukhtar just do not *demand* answers. If somebody has a solution, don't tell him that you wont do it because it worked on ONE kind of device. Have you tried my solution at least?